# If checkbox checked - select all cells in row?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

So I finally was able to copy selected rows over to a new datatable for a second datagridview.  However I have to selected each row.  I have a checkboxcolumn I'd like to use instead for selected each row however I'm not sure how to fit it into what I've done here.  I'll post the 2 things I've mentioned.

```
    Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk)
    chk.HeaderText = "Cart"
    chk.Name = "checkBoxColumnName"
```

The code above is for the checkbox on datagridview1.  Below is my code for datagridview2.  again, this work by selected all the rows I want on datagridview1 for datagridview2 but I'd like my checkbox column to be all you need to select the row for the code below.

```
    Dim Cart As New DataTable
    Cart.Columns.Add("Part Number")
    Cart.Columns.Add("Part Description")
    Cart.Columns.Add("Quan. Avail.")
    Cart.Columns.Add("U of M")
    Cart.Columns.Add("Min")
    Cart.Columns.Add("Vendor")
    Cart.Columns.Add("Vendor Part Number")
    Cart.Columns.Add("Location")

    Dim drow As DataRow
    For i As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        drow = Cart.NewRow
        drow("Part Number") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("MTI_PART_NO").Value
        drow("Part Description") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("DESCRIPTION").Value
        drow("Quan. Avail.") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("STOCKROOM_QTY").Value
        drow("U of M") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("UOM").Value
        drow("Min") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("MIN_QTY").Value
        drow("Vendor") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("VendorID").Value
        drow("Vendor Part Number") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("VendorNO").Value
        drow("Location") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("HOME_LOCATION").Value
        Cart.Rows.Add(drow)
    Next

    DataGridView2.DataSource = Cart.DefaultView
```

I tried this but doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure if I did it right.

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        Dim chkCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DirectCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        If Convert.ToBoolean(chkCell.Value) = True Then

            Dim drow As DataRow
            For i As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                drow = Cart.NewRow
                drow("Part Number") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("MTI_PART_NO").Value
                drow("Part Description") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("DESCRIPTION").Value
                drow("Quan. Avail.") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("STOCKROOM_QTY").Value
                drow("U of M") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("UOM").Value
                drow("Min") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("MIN_QTY").Value
                drow("Vendor") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("VendorID").Value
                drow("Vendor Part Number") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("VendorNO").Value
                drow("Location") = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells("HOME_LOCATION").Value
                Cart.Rows.Add(drow)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView2.DataSource = Cart.DefaultView
```

Comment: Just loop thru all the rows and test if that cell is T/F.  You should give your controls names.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to write it.  Back on it again this morning, hoping it "clicks" with me shortly.

Comment: I added something I was trying above.  It doesn't work but it also wouldn't selected everything the way I do now manually if the box was checked.

Comment: Loop thru *all* rows not *selectedrows*.  and `If dv1.Rows(i).Cells("Cart").Value = True Then...`  There is also an easier way to clone a dararow.  Rows in your Cart datatable wont "fit" in any database table though.